# Format decimal value to string with leading spaces

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string-formatting

How do I format a decimal value to a string with a single digit after the comma/dot and leading spaces for values less than 100?

For example, a decimal value of `12.3456` should be output as `" 12.3"` with single leading space. `10.011` would be `" 10.0"`. `123.123` is `"123.1"`

I'm looking for a solution, that works with standard/custom string formatting, i.e.

```
decimal value = 12.345456;
Console.Write("{0:magic}", value); // 'magic' would be a fancy pattern.
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This pattern `{0,5:###.0}` should work:

```
string.Format("{0,5:###.0}", 12.3456) //Output  " 12.3"
string.Format("{0,5:###.0}", 10.011)  //Output  " 10.0" 
string.Format("{0,5:###.0}", 123.123) //Output  "123.1"
string.Format("{0,5:###.0}", 1.123)   //Output  "  1.1"
string.Format("{0,5:###.0}", 1234.123)//Output "1234.1"
```

Comment: It most certainly does! Thanks! :)

Comment: Is there a good reference for this? i.e. what does each part do if my use case is slightly different.

Comment: @tjrobinson everything is on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: If you need a leading zero for values between -1.0 and 1.0, the pattern should be altered to `{0,5:##0.0}`.

Comment: Can I do it via ToString(...)?

Answer (score 55):

Another one with string interpolation (C# 6+):

```
double x = 123.456;
$"{x,15:N4}"// left pad with spaces to 15 total, numeric with fixed 4 decimals
```

Expression returns: `"       123.4560"`

Answer (score 13):

```
value.ToString("N1");
```

Change the number for more decimal places.

EDIT: Missed the padding bit

```
value.ToString("N1").PadLeft(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. But the use of PadLeft won't work in my case, the string with the {0:...} placeholder is going to contain more text than just the decimal value.

Comment: @Taz: You have to write `PadLeft(5)'. The parameter is the total length of the string to be padded.

Comment: @Jakob: Why can't you use `string.Format()`?

Comment: So whats the problem with PadLeft?

Comment: `PadLeft(value.ToString().Length + 1)` then I guess ;)

Ignoring the issue of more stuff in the string of course. You cant just split it up and then combine them back together to print them?

Comment: @Taz: No. Simply `PadLeft(5)`

Comment: Thanks! If I can, I avoid string.format. This here is much easier to maintain later without all those cryptic string codes.

Answer (score 3):

Many good answers, but this is what I use the most (c# 6+):

```
Debug.WriteLine($"{height,6:##0.00}");
//if height is 1.23 =>   "  1.23"
//if height is 0.23 =>   "  0.23"
//if height is 123.23 => "123.23"
```

Answer (score 0):

All above solution will do rounding of decimal, just in case somebody is searching for solution without rounding

```
decimal dValue = Math.Truncate(1.199999 * 100) / 100;
dValue .ToString("0.00");//output 1.99
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the "." could be a "," depending on Region settings, when using string.Format.

```
string.Format("{0,5:###.0}", 0.9)     // Output  "   .9"
string.Format("{0,5:##0.0}", 0.9)     // Output  "  0.9"
```

I ended up using this:

```
string String_SetRPM = $"{Values_SetRPM,5:##0}";
// Prints for example "    0", " 3000", and "24000"

string String_Amps = $"{(Values_Amps * 0.1),5:##0.0}";
// Print for example "  2.3"
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the accepted answer will produce **"  .1"** in case of **0.123**, which might be unexpected.

Therefore I'd prefer using 0.0 instead of ###.0 as number format. But it depends on your needs (see bottom of my comment).

**Examples:**

```
string.Format("{0,5:0.0}", 199.34) // Output "199.3"
string.Format("{0,5:0.0}",  19.34) // Output " 19.3"
string.Format("{0,5:0.0}",   0.34) // Output "  0.3"
```

**Explaining {0,5:0.0}**

Pattern: {{index},{padding}:{numberFormat}}

- *{index}*: zero based index of the parameter to be formatted out of a list of parameters passed to string.Format("format", param0, param1, param2...)
- *{padding}*: number of leading spaces to pad
- *{numberFormat}*: the actual number format to apply on the number

**Padding** documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros

**Custom Number Format** doucmentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

It is worth to compare the difference between 0 and # decimal specifier:

**0 decimal specifier**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#Specifier0

**# decimal specifier**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierD