# Format Numeric Value with Leading Spaces

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to format a numeric value with leading spaces, to pack the string out to a given length, thus:-

```
mystring = mynumber.ToString ("format-string")
```

but am having no luck finding the correct format string. I have seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293392/format-decimal-value-to-string-with-leading-spaces) and tried the answer suggested, but it doesn't work. For 123.4,

```
.ToString ("####.#")        gets "123.4"
.ToString ("6:####.#")      gets "6:123.4"
.ToString ("0,6:####.#")    gets "06:0,123.4"
.ToString ("{####.#}")      gets "{123.4}"
.ToString ("{6:####.#}")    gets "{6:123.4}"
.ToString ("{0,6:####.#}")  gets "{06:0,123.4}"
```

Is there anything I can try to get `" 123.4"`?

Comment: Do you always want 1 leading space or do you want the string padded to a certain length?

Comment: @Jodrell, I want the string padded to a certain length; sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: To be clear, the "certain length" that the questioner seemed strangely unwilling to state, is 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use the `ToString` method for that format, you need to use the `String.Format` method:

```
String.Format("{0,6:####.#}", number)
```

Comment: are you sure that makes a difference?

Comment: @Jodrell: Yes. The ",6" part can't be used with ToString as there is no index to attach it to. The ToString method only uses the format string itself, i.e. the part after the colon.

Comment: @Guffa, Thank you. I was beginning to suspect something of that sort.