# Building a string that starts with a number and the second part of the string is to have a common indent

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm building a value to display in a dropdown Select box.  This value consists of a currency value, then a username.  What I would like is that the usernames all start with the same indent.

Ex (what I have currently):

```
$1,000  UserA
$100  UserB
$10  UserC
```

What I would like:

```
$1,000  UserA
$100    UserB
$10     UserC
```

or even better:

```
$1,000  UserA
  $100  UserB
   $10  UserC
```

As I see the third list as the most readable.

Is there an easy way to do this without writing a function where I examine the max length, and then format it manually or a "cheat" to accomplish this?

**Edit: How I generate the ViewModel items (what I pass to my Webpage)**

```
    public ActionResult SearchCollections()
    {
        SearchCollectionGridViewModel scgvm = new SearchCollectionGridViewModel();

        var UserNamesWithValues = (from ud in db.userdetails  //build the dataset to pass to the View
                                   join usr in db.my_aspnet_users on ud.IdUsers equals usr.id                                       
                                   select new { 
                                       UserName = usr.name, 
                                       TradeCollectionValue = ud.TradeCollectionValue,
                                       NumberOfTrades = ud.NumberOfTrades,
                                       DollarValueTraded = ud.TradeValue
                                        }).ToList();

        scgvm.TradeCollectionValues = (from c in UserNamesWithValues
                                       where c.TradeCollectionValue > 0
                                       orderby c.TradeCollectionValue descending
                                       select new SelectListItem
                                       {
                                           Text = String.Format("{0,5} {1}", c.TradeCollectionValue, c.UserName).Replace(" ", "\xA0"),
                                           Value = c.UserName
                                       }).ToList();

         return View(scgvm);
     }
```

**Edit #2: Answer found /figured out**

I used the answer below plus the following two links to generate a string that was accurate in the Selectbox: (Monospace font will be a key as well)

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828697/how-to-retain-spaces-in-dropdownlist-asp-net-mvc-razor-views)

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293392/format-decimal-value-to-string-with-leading-spaces)

Comment: normally we have to insert some `tab` characters, however this will work only if we use `fixed-size` font.

Comment: @KingKing As this is a Web App I'm not sure I can completely control that requirement.

Comment: are you using a web form control?

Comment: @DanielA.White It is MVC 4 so it's a Razor Helper Function that I populate via the View Model, Ex: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DollarValueTraded, Model.DollarValueTraded, "Dollar Value Traded...", new { @class = "DropDownLists"})`

Comment: you might consider another control such as select2.

Comment: @Mark if you deal with web, you should use `Table` layout, it's right for this purpose.

Comment: @KingKing This isn't a CSS layout issue, but a string formatting issue, (unless I'm way out to lunch) where I want the values inside the Select box to be as indicated in the 2nd and 3rd example above.  Going to test Jan's solution.

Comment: @Mark `table layout` is not part of `CSS`, it's `HTML` stuff. All the layout related to `alignment` should use `Table layout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0,5} {1}", money, username)
```

Or, HTML-encoded,

```
Replace(String.Format("{0,5} {1}", money, username), " ", "&nbsp;")
```

So in MVC4 it would look "somewhat like" this:

```
@Html.Raw(
    Replace(
        String.Format(
            "{0,5} {1}",
            money,
            HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(username)
        ),
        " ",
        "&nbsp;"
    )
)
```

(make sure to set the font to something monospaced)

Comment: How would I generate such a format when I am building the string on the controller (server side).  See the edit above.

Comment: Figured it out with a bit of help from a couple of other SO answers, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a tab with `\t`?

Comment: See my answer to KingKing