# Issue with Formatting a double variable to show in textbox in C#

Tags: c#, string, format

Does anyone know why this Format command produces the following strange results:

```
textbox1.Text = String.Format("{0:+;-}{0,7:0.000;0.000}", dblVariable);
```

Here are the strange results (check the signs of the formatted text - the sign is incorrect for numbers smaller than 0.5):

```
dblVariable       textbox1.Text
-0.100000         + 0.100
-0.200000         + 0.200
-0.300000         + 0.300
-0.400000         + 0.400
-0.500000         - 0.500
```

Thanks

Comment: Like dotnetom said, what is so strange about the results?  That's probably why your question was down voted.  You need to provide more info.  -1 for assuming we are mind readers :) (I didn't actually down vote).

Comment: I modified the question!

Comment: Okay, here's my advice.  Modify your question so that is *plainly clear what the problem is*.  Don't just say "check the signs of the formatted text"; say something like "The doubles all have a negative value but the formatted output is showing a `+` sign in most cases".  Don't make it a vague guessing game for people.

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce the issue. [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/jwbwpF) . can you create a small demo that does show the problem?

Comment: With your code, I get the exact same strange result on my system. (+  0.100
+  0.200
+  0.300
+  0.400
-  0.500)

Comment: @NESHOM - I copy and pasted that from your example to show that it works fine. Have you stepped through and verified the value of `dblVariable`?

Comment: Yes, I created a new project, copy-pasted your piece of code to a button event and it gives me the exact same strange result!

Comment: @Sayse - based on dotnetom's answer, I wonder how did you get the right output using my code?!

Comment: @NESHOM - IDEOne uses the mono compiler I believe, did you see the std out in that link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [article in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator) describes the issue. Look at what is said next to `Two sections`:

> If the number to be formatted is negative, but becomes zero after
>   rounding according to the format in the second section, the resulting
>   zero is formatted according to the first section.

In your case the format of the sign is `{0:+;-}`. This effectively means that there is no number format, just sign format. So when rounding to this format it must be rounded to a integer number. So in case of `-0.1` to `-0.4` the number is rounded to 0, which uses first section (+), but `-0.5` is rounded to `-1`, so second section (-) is used.

You can fix it by only using single format:

```
textbox1.Text = String.Format("{0,7:+ 0.000;- 0.000}", dblVariable)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I want. I have several textbox controls that are vertically aligned. I want them all to show the values right-aligned with the floating points also vertically aligned and they also show signs. Here is my original question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27511347/3179989. Any solution?

Comment: I updated answer to use `{0,7:...` instead of `{0:...`

Comment: Thank you, but this still does not make the floating points vertically aligned . Please check my question where I listed an example of what I am looking for http://stackoverflow.com/q/27511347/3179989

Comment: So no way to do this?

Comment: In that case - no. However the answer explains why you get `+` where you expect to get `-`

Comment: @NESHOM - You need to use a monospaced font if you wish for the text to be aligned also