# How to print matrix?

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array, overriding, tostring

```
public override string ToString() {
    string matrixView = "";

    for (int r=0; r<=this.rows; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<=this.columns; c++) {
                
        }
    }

    return matrixView;
}
```

Note:
##################################
`this.rows` = row number
`this.columns` = column number
`this.matrix`= 2-dimensional array used as data store
##################################

In this code, I aim to make seem for example 4x4 matrix like:

`[0 0 0 0]`
`[0 0 0 0]`
`[0 0 0 0]`
`[0 0 0 0]`

Each newline must be started with "[". Values(`this.columns` times) and spaces(`this.columns`-1 times) must be printed. Finally, the line must be ended with "]\n"
And these operations above must be done `this.rows`times.

I think in this way. But nested loops always make me confuse. So, I tried several times but I couldn't be successful at it. And `String.Concat` threw `NullReferenceException`when I tried  to concaten `matrixView` with "[", "]\n" and `this.matrix[r, c].ToString()`.

Comment: Can you please share with us the definition of the `matrix`?

Comment: matrix is a int[,](two-dminsional int array) field in Matrix struct which is initalized in struct constructor with int rows and int columns. So matrix is int[this.rows, this.columns](two-dimesional array with initalized rows and column numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public override string ToString() {
    // When building string, better use StringBuilder instead of String
    StringBuilder matrixView = new StringBuilder();

    // Note r < matrix.GetLength(0), matrix is zero based [0..this.rows - 1]
    // When printing array, let's query this array - GetLength(0)
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.GetLength(0); r++) {
        // Starting new row we should add row delimiter 
        if (r > 0)
            matrixView.AppendLine();

        // New line starts from [
        matrixView.Append("["); 

        // Note r < matrix.GetLength(1), matrix is zero based [0..this.rows - 1]
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix.GetLength(1); c++) {
            // Starting new column we should add column delimiter 
            if (c > 0)
                matrixView.Append(' ');

            matrixView.Append(matrix[r, c]);       
        }

        // New line ends with [
        matrixView.Append("]");
    }

    return matrixView.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could for example do something like:

```
for (int r=0; r<=this.rows; r++) {
    var s = "[";
    for (int c=0; c<=this.columns; c++) {
        s += myValue.ToString() + " "; 
    }
    s += "]";
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

But if you numbers are larger than 9 you might want to [pad the numbers with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293392/format-decimal-value-to-string-with-leading-spaces). It is not very efficient to do many small concatenations like this. But unless you do this very frequently it will not matter.